# Event Notification: Java design patten

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am working on a project which has several modules. I have a module which is at the base and which is common to all modules.
I have a business object (this is singleton class) in the base module and this can fire an event that something is done.

I want each module to be able to listen to this event and do some specific things.

What is the best way to do this ?

The common module is the first code that is being executed at the application start up and as this is base it cannot call modules above it.

EDITS:
I think the question is somewhat not complete considering my scenario. Below is an explanation.

I have a singleton class ( I make this as immutable ). This class is present in the base module. It has a static method `getInstance()` which will initialize a new object based on the data stored in a table. 
There is a background scheduler which will regularly update the data in that table with the latest data from the server. Currently what I am doing is that scheduler is directly interacting with the table. 
1. I don't want any external access to that data. I am thinking of providing a static method in singleton class like

```
protected static void doPeriodicUpdate() {
}
```

And call this method from background scheduler like

```
MySingleTonClass.doPeriodicCheck();
```

Is having a static method good approach ?

The singleton class can fire some events at any time like

```
1. MyEventOne
2. MyEventTwo
```

Listeners who are listening to these events will get a handle of `mysingletonclass` object and will perform some specific functions. As this object is created it will be destroyed only at tomcat shutdown. At tomcat startup I have a init servlet which is initializing this singleton object and putting it in servlet context so that any class that want this object can access it.
These events will be fired when something happens and after that I have to update the table. For that also I am planning to have static methods in singleton class like

```
protected static void doSomething(String arg0) {
     // This will do something on database
     // After completion
     fireMyEventOne();
}

// Something happened at client side. Client will call the rest service and rest service will call static method like

class MyRestService extends MySingleTonClass {
      MySingleTonClass.doSomething();
}
```

Like this there can be others events which can be fired when something else happened at client side. Client will call rest services in a same way.

I have a feeling that something is wrong with this approach. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the event bus included in [Google's Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained). It is designed pretty much exactly for your use case: one part of your application fires an event, while another subscribes to these events, without these two parts having to have knowledge of each other (which would usually be the case if you solved it by registering the event handlers of the outside modules on the base module).

I think their example gives a pretty good taste of what it is like to use the library:

```
// Class is typically registered by the container.
class EventBusChangeRecorder {
    @Subscribe public void recordCustomerChange(ChangeEvent e) {
      recordChange(e.getChange());
    }
}

// somewhere during initialization
eventBus.register(new EventBusChangeRecorder());

// much later
public void changeCustomer() {
    ChangeEvent event = getChangeEvent();
    eventBus.post(event);
}
```

In your case, your base module would be the part posting to the event bus, whereas the other modules would have methods annotated with `@Subscribe`. All you need to ensure is that the modules can share one instance of the event bus, which you could do by, for example, creating it in the base module and then allowing the other modules to access it.